# Why I am getting a Typescript error while using useContext with React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-state, use-context

I am creating a Context using useContext with TypeScript. I have a function into seperate file *MovieDetailProvider.tsx* as wrapper in my App.tsx file.

```
import { Context, MovieObject } from '../interfaces/interfaces'

export const MovieDetailContext = React.createContext<Context | {}>({})

const MovieDetailProvider: React.FC<React.ReactNode> = ({ children }) => {

    const [movieData, setMovieData] = React.useState<MovieObject | {}>({})

    return (
        <MovieDetailContext.Provider value={{movieData, setMovieData}}>
                {children}
        </MovieDetailContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default MovieDetailProvider
```

Here is Context and MovieObject Interfaces:

```
export interface Context {
    movieData: MovieObject,
    setMovieData: (movieData: MovieObject) => void
}

export interface MovieObject {
    loading: boolean,
    error: any,
    data: any
}
```

Also I have 2 components which are "Consumers" using hooks useContext for exchanging data. But when trying to get context with useContext like this:

```
import { MovieDetailContext } from './MovieDetailProvider'

const MovieDetail: React.FC = () => {

    const { movieData, setMovieData } = useContext<Context>(MovieDetailContext)
....
```

and

```
import { MovieDetailContext } from './MovieDetailProvider'


const MovieList:React.FC = () => {

    const { movieData, setMovieData } = useContext<Context>(MovieDetailContext)
....
```

I have an error in the same place (MovieDetailContext is underlined) in two files.
The error is

```
TypeScript error in /home/glib/ReactCourse/graphql-project/client/src/components/MovieDetail.tsx(8,61):
Argument of type 'Context<{} | Context>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Context<Context>'.
  The types of 'Provider.propTypes' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'WeakValidationMap<ProviderProps<{} | Context>> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'WeakValidationMap<ProviderProps<Context>> | undefined'.
      Type 'WeakValidationMap<ProviderProps<{} | Context>>' is not assignable to type 'WeakValidationMap<ProviderProps<Context>>'.
        Types of property 'value' are incompatible.
          Type 'Validator<{} | Context> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Validator<Context> | undefined'.
            Type 'Validator<{} | Context>' is not assignable to type 'Validator<Context>'.
              Type '{} | Context' is not assignable to type 'Context'.
                Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Context'.  TS2345
```

I dont have much experirnce with Typescript and I dont have an idea how to fix this Context error.
If anyone has an advice or solution please help: )
Thanks

P.S. This is my App.tsx file

```
imports...

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
})

const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}> 
      <MovieDetailProvider>
        <h1>Your Movie List</h1>
        <MovieList/>
        <AddMovie/>
        <MovieDetail/>
      </MovieDetailProvider>
    </ApolloProvider>


  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

`React.useContext<Context>(MovieDetailContext)` expects a parameter of type `<Context>` but your passing in MovieDetailContext which is of type `<Context | {}>`

You should remove the empty object from the context type and either set it to undefined or the object with the values set to undefined

```
 export const MovieDetailContext = React.createContext<Context>(undefined);
```

Same issue with movieData when passing in the value for the Provider it's expecting MovieObject so you need set the type fro the state to a simple MOvieObject and pass in a MovieObject or undefined for initial value

```
const [movieData, setMovieData] = React.useState<MovieObject>(undefined)
```

Answer (score 1):

You problaly need to adapt the type of your `useContext` statement to match the type of your `createContext` statement:

```
// change from
useContext<Context>(MovieDetailContext)
// to
useContext<Context | {}>(MovieDetailContext)
```